# Kotlin compiler argument not applied to scratch file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, scratch-file

I wanted to use `kotlin.time.measureTime` in a Kotlin scratch file but it doesn't work.

```
...
kotlinOptions {
    ...
    freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xopt-in=kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime"]
}
```

[image: experimental-annotation]

Of course in my scratch file I "use classpath of module" which defines the compiler argument. When I use `measureTime` in regular code it works fine, but in the scratch file doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

@OptIn works for me (see alternative recommendation by IntelliJ IDEA).

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
val s = measureTime { sleep(10) }
println(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit declaration of experimental API usage inside scratch file:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalTime
val s = measureTime {
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. The annotation is "applicable" but the code still fails in runtime with the same error - This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime' or '@OptIn(kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime::class)'